# Elucidating an unknown compound using 1H- and 13C-NMR spectral data

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, molecular-structure, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I am currently struggling with the following NMR spectrum for this compound:

[image: Proton and carbon NMT spectra of unknown]

I know for sure that we should multiply the integrals of the hydrogen atoms by four, and that the compound contains at least one ethoxy group. Furthermore, the molar mass of the compound is estimated to be $\pu{258g/mol}$. We tried our best, but could not find the solution. We also figured that we should multiply the $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ by two, but aren't sure about it. Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Did you ascertain the sample is uniform (only one molecule of interest), e.g., by chromatography? How many different signals you count for the 13C/for 1H NMR spectrum?  What does the chemical shift and multiplicity of the signals tell?  Instead of  «we should multiply the 13C-NMR by two», likely your intent was in lines of «there are (at least) six types of carbon atoms». Did you record an IR spectrum, e.g. to check for the presence of $\ce{-NH2}$ or $\ce{-OH}$?  Is the estimate of $\pu{258 g/mol}$ what aim for in your synthesis, or result of an analysis by MS?

Comment: Typically, you know the reagents used in a synthesis, and anticipate a transformation; this knowledge may render some of the characterizations to combine less important.

Comment: I'm no NMR specialist, and I'm not sure pending closing reason as HW is justified, but it appears that the question lacks details. Please add as much data as possible, such as sample preparation, experiment conditions, and, in case you also performed analysis with another instrumental method, provide supplementary data (FTIR/UV-Vis/HPLC/MS/ICP-AES/…).

Comment: I do not think the homework chose reason is justified either. Is personally prefer tabulated data though; especially in this case it'll also help us understand how you interpret the signals. Like when you write that there is an ethoxy group, it would be good to know how you have deduced that.

Comment: It was in my previous exam. I was given no other information than the two diagrams, and I was supposed to deduce the structure with just the information available, which I already gave. As 81% failed this question, the professor told us we were supposed to look for an ethoxy group, no other information

Comment: @冰淇淋 If you perceive the need to train how to resolve such puzzles, have a look at the spectroscopy section of the page's [resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry). The Silverstein book taps more into teaching theory and reference, the ones by Field more into the practical training to combine UV-Vis, MS, IR, NMR.  Depending on the level you want to apply them later on your own, the 2D NMR book by Field may go beyond your needs, which you might check with your instructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appreciate Karsten Theis for his effort to solve this problem, but I have to say that I completely disagree with the structure he has come with as the answer (as a matter of fact, I came up with the same structure but it didn't fit the given $\ce{^1H}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum; *vide infra*). Followings are my reasons:

As correctly pointed out by Karsten Theis, the resonance at about $\pu{174 ppm}$ of the $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum indicates a presence of an ester carbonyl carbon. The quartet at about $\pu{4.05 ppm}$ and triplet at about $\pu{1.15 ppm}$ in $\ce{^{1}H}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum indicates a presence of $\ce{-O-CH2-CH3}$
group, as hinted by OP's teacher. The presence of $\ce{-O-CH2\!-}$ fragment is confirmed by the resonance at about $\pu{60.0 ppm}$ in $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum.

The second triplet at about $\pu{2.20 ppm}$ in $\ce{^{1}H}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum also indicates a presence of $\ce{-CH2-C(=O)-}$ fragment. Thus, Karsten Theis' suggestion of the presence of $\ce{-CH2-CO-O-CH2-CH3}$ fragment is correct. But here is the problem. The proton signal of $\ce{-CH2-C(=O)-}$ fragment displays a triplet, not a doublet as Karsten Theis' suggested structure would have given in reality. Consequently, most possible fragment should have been $\ce{-CH2-CH2-CO-O-CH2-CH3}$ (total of 5 carbons).

Since the $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum shows only 6 carbon resonances and the molar mass of the compound is suggested to be about $\pu{258 g mol-1}$, the compound should have at least one plane of symmetry as suggested by OP. It is also noteworthy that the intensity of the third carbon from the right in $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectrum is almost double compared to other possible $\ce{-CH2 \!-}$ carbon signals. Therefore, arguably, the compound should have at least two $\ce{-CH2-CH2-CO-O-CH2-CH3}$ fragments plus two $\ce{-CH2 \!-}$ parts, giving that $\ce{C14H26O4}$ molecular formula (molar mass of which come up as $\pu{258.36 g mol-1}$ that agrees with the given value). Thus the structure should be:

[image: diethyl decanedioate]

The molecule is diethyl decanedioate, with molecular formula of $\ce{C14H26O4}$  and molar mass of $\pu{258.36 g mol-1}$. To confirm the structure, let's look at the integrations given in $\ce{^{1}H}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$. The proton signal of $\ce{-CH2-C(=O)-}$ at around $\pu{2.2 ppm}$ is integrated as $1.00$, meaning one proton is equivalent to $0.25$ integration value. The integration value of the triplet and the multiplet coincided with it at the range of $\pu{1.1-1.3 ppm}$ is marked as $3.5$, thus is equivalent to  14 protons $(\frac{3.5}{0.25} = 14)$. Also, the integrations of multiplet at $\pu{1.55 ppm}$ and quartet at $\pu{4.05 ppm}$ are marked as $\approx 1$, and hence each of them is equivalent to  4 protons. Thus, the total proton count is $3 \times 4 + 14 = 26$ protons, which agrees with the suggested molecular formula.

Further, the ChemDraw stimulated $\ce{^{1}H}$- and $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectra for the suggested molecule are shown below:

[image: ChemDraw suggested Spectra]

Both spectra are in good agreement with actual spectra, specifically see the overlapped carbon signals at around $\pu{29 ppm}$. However, the triplet at around $\pu{1.07 ppm}$ has moved downfield to $\pu{1.17 ppm}$ in real time spectrum, showing more deshielded nature, probably due to the presence of oxygen at $\beta$-position.

---

**Edit:**

As Buttonwood has suggested, it is always better to compare your data with experimentally recorded data. The SDBS Database, which provides the spectral data of compound in interest under [SDBS 2666](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=2666) has given following $\ce{^{1}H}$- and $\ce{^{13}C}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectra to compare:

[image: Published 1H-NMR of the compound]
[image: Published 13C-NMR of the compound]

Both spectra match the given spectra of the compound.

Comment: *Suggestion:* While there are programs to predict NMR spectra (*predict* as in *a more or less reasonable/educated guess*) sometimes plot cleaner/simpler than eventually met in the lab, I think the *additional* comparison with *experimentally recorded* data were beneficial for this question, as well as a habit to adopt in general for the training of spectroscopic identification of molecules. Diethyl decanedioate/diethyl sebacate is filed as entry #2666 in the [SDBS database](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=2666), thankfully, with NMR recorded in $\ce{CDCl3}$, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood: Thanks for the suggestion and the database. I have edited my answer accordingly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the hint from your instructor and the 13-C signal at 175 ppm fits nicely to a $\ce{-CH2-CO-O-CH2-CH3}$ fragment, i.e an ester. The 13-C spectrum shows only 6 peaks and the molar mass is about 258 g/mol, so there is probably some symmetry in the molecule.

There is something that puzzles me. The signals around 1.2 ppm in the proton NMR integrate to 3.5, so after doubling (to explain the other peaks as $\ce{CH2}$ groups), we get 7. There is a $\ce{CH3}$ group already accounted for (from the ethoxy group), so there would be another two $\ce{CH2}$ groups (or even more $\ce{XH}$ groups). That means there are at least 6 different signals in the proton NMR, but just 6 different peaks in the 13-C NMR. With one coming from the carbonyl, that's a mismatch and we need another carbon. One of the peaks in the 13-C NMR is about twice as high, so maybe that's the solution to this puzzle.

A possible molecular formula would be $\ce{C14H26O4}$. That would mean all the signals in the proton NMR are "doubled up" because of symmetry, and all of the ones in the 13-C NMR as well, except for one that corresponds to four carbons.

I did not find a structure that satisfies all of these constraints. The closest I could find is this:

[image]

This has the correct number of 13-C peaks with pretty good matching of chemical shifts, and explains much of the proton NMR as well. Unfortunately, the molar mass is off by 2 (degree of unsaturation is 3 instead of 2), and one of the signals has an integral that is too low, and the signal at 2.2 ppm in the proton NMR would be a doublet instead of the observed triplet. This incorrect structure, however, does illustrate how having different degree of symmetry in different parts of the molecule can explain the number of signals found in the 13-C spectrum.